# Deallocation error in Xcode while using ARC

Tags: ios, mkmapview, automatic-ref-counting

Im setting up a map, with some MKAnnotation. When i add them to the map, I receive this message:

An instance 0xbe62850 of class ENTAnottation was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
 (
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0xbe66b30>

If i am not mistaken, that means that an object has been deallocated while their observer are still alive. How can I know wich are the observers? and, even if I find them... isn't explicit deallocation forbidden with ARC? if thats true, i could not deallocate them... so... what could i do?

Thank you.

-------EDIT------

By request, I post my code. I make a call to a web that returns me a JSON with the values that I need to set my Annotations:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
responseString = [request responseString];
id jsonObject = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
NSLog(@"From the JSON: %@", responseString);
NSMutableArray *lat = [jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"latitud"];
NSMutableArray *lon = [jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"longitud"];
NSMutableArray *azafatas = [jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"azafata"];
NSMutableArray *usernames = [jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"username"];
NSMutableArray *mapazafatas=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<[lat count]; i++)
{
    ENTAnottation *azafata=[[ENTAnottation alloc]init];
    double latidouble=[[lat objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];
    double longdouble=[[lon objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees lati=latidouble;
    CLLocationDegrees longi=longdouble;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lati, longi);
    NSString *nombre=[azafatas objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *email=[usernames objectAtIndex:i];
    azafata.coordinate=coords;
    azafata.title=nombre;
    azafata.username=email;
    [mapazafatas addObject:azafata];
    //[mapa addAnnotation:azafata];
}
for (int i=0;i<[mapazafatas count];i++)
{
    [mapa addAnnotation:[mapazafatas objectAtIndex:i]];
}
}
```

After that, the app crashes, despite it goes through my code without any problem.

Comment: Post code, memory addresses cannot help for anything...

Comment: Found this, in case someone has the same problem that I have (not good news) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804900/possible-bug-in-mkmapview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Obviously, if you pass an impossible pair of coordinates it throws to your face that very clear, and impossible to confuse anybody, error message. Pity me...